# Locall MySQL DB login Error : Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, authentication

I have the weirdest MySQL login problem ever!

The DBMS is installed on my desktop and I'm accessing it locally, not through a network or internet.

When I try to connect to it via cmd:

```
mysql -u root -proot;
```

it connects perfectly..

but, when I try to connect through a Java program in NetBeans:

```
Connection con = null;

String url ="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb";
String user ="root";
String password ="root";

try
{          
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);
}
Catch(Exception e)
{ 
     System.out.println(e.toString() );
}
```

it throws an exception !!

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I have the mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar library added to NetBeans..
It was working before, not sure why it is not working now!!

Also, when I connect to MySQL like this:

```
mysql -u root -p;
```

then I enter the password, it gives this error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so stupid ~~~
I found the problem ... 
Here's why this is happening and how I solved it:

Reason of problem: I changed the password for root from blank to 'root'

Then, I couldn't connect to MySQL from Java ..

it turns out I have to update the privileges of the database after changing the password.

So I did that by:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON [database_name].* to '[user]'@'[hostname]' identified by '[password]'
```

and now it works 100%

Answer (score 0):

```
Connection con = null;
String dbase = "database";
String dbuser = "root";
String dbpass = "";

    try{

                String ConnString;

                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                ConnString = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+dbase+"?user="+dbuser+"&password="+dbpass;
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnString);
                //System.out.println("Connection to database successful!");

            }catch(Exception e){

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Try this?